# Process Large number of zipped xml files in s3 bucket

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

I have a very large number of xml files zipped and sitting in s3 bucket. What will be the best way to process the data in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need to do with them or what is the nature of the processing operations required.

But I would look into [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/batch-ops.html):

> S3 Batch Operations performs **large-scale batch operations** on Amazon S3 objects. You can use S3 Batch Operations to copy objects, set object tags or access control lists (ACLs), initiate object restores from Amazon S3 Glacier, or invoke an **AWS Lambda function** to perform custom actions using your objects.

Comment: Sorry for being vague in my question. To be specifc I want to run query on the data after appending each row defined by each xml file

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra Hi. You could use Glue to [convert xml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html) into csv/json, and then use [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) to query resulted files in new format.